# How to hide inactive slides on jquery cycle

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-cycle

I am using jquery cycle to cycle through a large number of customer reviews, with a numbered pager and 6 items per page. My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {              
        $('.reviews')
            .before('<div id="banner-nav">')
            .cycle({
                fx:'fadeout', 
                timeout: 5000,
                pager: '#banner-nav'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need the reviews to be transparent (text only) as there is a background image that needs to be visible. The problem is that since jquery cycle does not hide inactive slides, I get an effect like the following:

[image]

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/7jok549x/ for an example

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please share your site link. Then we could help. @Marc

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7jok549x/

Comment: If you save the review-div-IDs in a array for the javascript and loop through them? If x is selected, set the visiblity:visible; else visibility:collapsed;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the  `fx:'fadeout',` line from the options.

This options shows all and just hides the active one.

The default (*when you remove it*) is to fade in the active one.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7jok549x/3/

Comment: In my opinion this answer directly solves the problem, and will help future visitors better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It starts with your CSS. Adding position property value of **absolute** and also a **background-colo**r to **.review** Will be a good start.

```
.review {
position: absolute; /* that stacks them on top of each other */
background-color: white; /* You need a background so you don't see the ones behind */
}
```

[See working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/7jok549x/4/)

Comment: Sorry, but you may have missed this line in my question:`I need the reviews to be transparent (text only) as there is a background image that needs to be visible.`. That part is important.

Comment: Check it again. Like gabby said, you don't need fx:'fadeout; remove it, if  not, you need a background.

Comment: I was just referring to your comment `background-color: white; /* You need a background so you don't see the ones behind */`

Comment: Cleaned out your other code while I was fixing it. If you add them back, it will be just fine-no difference.